# How to make war can see and inject bean from ear mobule

Tags: javabeans, war, ear

We have developed our system in many seperated war file and using @Stateless, @ApplicationScoped, @Inject in source code.

Now i want to make ear file like this,
but it looks like we can not inject Bean in ejb module into war file.

```
EAR  
 \-lib  
 |  \- utilityA.jar  
 |  \- utilityB.jar  
 |  \- ...  
 |- ejb-jarC.jar  
 |- ejb-jarD.jar  
 |- ...  
 |- warE.jar  
 |- warF.jar
```

Problems i found:
(1) With above structure, when @ApplicationScoped bean call initialize method, it get stuck on waiting Stateless component to init.

(2) I tried to add initialize-in-order to application.xml i got other problem that bean doest not have VIEW LOCAL.

Is there any way for us to config [visible] of bean in ejb module so that war can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution myself to make ear file.
But there are lot of problem i had to solve due to complexity of our project.

Here is some key point for someone looking for solution like me.
+ JPA (jar-file): You need to create a persistence module only contain persistence.xml. Then put jar-file into persistence.xml if you want to load entity in ejb module.
+ Application Scoped bean and init method: In wildfly/jboss, ApplicationScoped bean will be created for each war application.
And init method should not be used if that bean reference to a bean in other ejb module. If you want something to be init when war start, write a ContextListner and add it to web.xml.
+ All the web related  processing should be packed in war not in ejb module.

If you have question, can send me message so we can disscuss.